# mysqldump command not working?

Tags: mysql

I am using mysqldump to take backup of my database, but the command is not working..
the command i am using is `mysqldump -u root dbname> 'c:\backupdatafolder\backup.sql'`
i am running this command in MySQL cli but not running,..is there any thing wrong in the command?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You are supposed to run that on the command line of your operating system not on the MySQL CLI.

`cd` to the bin folder of MySQL first, something like `C:\mysql\bin` or wherever your MySQL is installed on

Comment: hey! @Bakkal but then also not working, giving the error "mysqldump is not recognized ..."

Comment: `cd` to the bin folder of MySQL first, something like `C:\mysql\bin` I think.

Comment: hey thanks @Bakkal, just forgot to set the class path...it worked, previously i was just running the command in MySQL CLI...Thanks a lot..

Comment: Thanks, it solved my problem. I replaced the `mysqldump` into `C:/xampp/mysql/bin/mysqldump.exe` and it worked fine!

Answer (score 2):

If the mysqldump can not be identified by your CMD prompt (I believe you are using Windows), then you first have to go to the bin folder where this command can be found. In my case, the path is "C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.5.24\bin", it would be more or less the same path for you. After that open your CMD prompt and go to this path by command "cd C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.5.24\bin". Now you should run your mysqldump command for taking the backup as you have been trying. Hope this helps!

Comment: If mysqldump is not identified by the cmd prompt that means it cannot recognize where the mysqldump.exe is located. You need to add path of the directory where the exe is located in the PATH variable under environment variables. After doing that your command will start working in the cmd prompt. However, this is not part of the best practices.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use MySQL Dump you must have added MySQL bin to path environment variable, this is cause MySQL Dump depends on MySQL binaries to work. And check the firewalls if you use one

Answer (score 0):

Place mysqldump.exe file where your 'backup.bat' file exists.
In the 'backup.bat' file write dump command and then run 'backup.bat' file.