# mysqldump and how to get it working?

Tags: php, mysql

In a previous question I enquired about the use of the SQL command LOAD DATA FILE and in the responses I was put into the track of using mysqldump to handle database backups, I got a little help in the understanding of this function but am now very stuck trying to get it to work.

Below is my code, please have a look and if you can see where I am going wrong could you possibly explain and show where? I have looked tirelessly on the net to try and find how to get my code to work but to no avail,

```
//Database Information
    $dbhost = "localhost";
    $dbname = "foobar";
    $dbuser = "foo";
    $dbpass = "bar";

    if (isset($_POST['backup'])):

        $command = "mysqldump --opt -host=$dbhost --user=$dbuser 
                    --password=$dbpass $dbname > /sql/backup/verypc.sql";
        system($command);

    endif;
```

Many thanks in advance anyone helping out.

Comment: What's going wrong?  "Doesn't work" is rather vague...

Comment: Sorry, well when I run the command it just loads up a success page (code not included above) and re-directs but no file gets created. I have tried mysqldump --help and that worked so I know its finding the *.exe and running but for some reason it wont create the *.sql file.

Comment: You might want to have a look at this thread. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979464/mysqldump-command-not-working/12262542#12262542

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `-host=$dbhost` instead of `--host=$dbhost`.

Comment: Changed it to --host but it still doesn't create the *.sql file :(

Comment: Then you have an error with one of your login settings.  Does the user you're connecting as have the appropriate permissions?  Also, like some others have said, make sure you can actually run commands from within a PHP script on your system.

Comment: The login settings are checked, there the same as the ones used to do normal database updates etcetera, it might be being able to run shell commands, if that is so I don't know how to check if I can or not.

Comment: Try something simple like `<?php echo exec("ls");?>` and see what you get.

Comment: that echo's out sql when run.

Comment: sql is a folder on the host on the same level as the includes folder which contains the file which is running the echo exec('ls'); script.

Comment: So commands are running fine.  Assuming your hosting allows SSH, does running the same mysqldump command directly from a command line work?  If not, what errors do you get?

Comment: Ill try that and get back to you. thank you for your help so far.

Comment: sorry I ran out of time today, ill try running the shell script from a command prompt tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

First you must ensure that your hosting lets you run shell commands with php. To achieve this, you should begin with a simple ls and see if it is displayed.

Otherwize, you can find some mysql-backup script written in php.

Comment: Quote Aif: "To achieve this, you should begin with a simple ls and see if it is displayed" what is an ls? sorry for not knowing.

Comment: ls is a unix command to list directory's content, this is a basical command.

Comment: Thank you, guess I'll have to ask a separate question on how to use that command in Unix.

Answer (score 0):

Use exec, not system.

Also, consider using a cronjob. I use this to backup my database hourly:

```
mysqldump --opt -Q -u [username] -p[password] [username] > /home/[username]/backups/`date --iso-8601`.sql
```

Comment: So you would suggest.....  $command = "mysqldump --opt -host=$dbhost --user=$dbuser 
                    --password=$dbpass $dbname > /sql/backup/verypc.sql";
        exec($command);

Comment: sadly doesn't work, maybe my host doesn't allow shell commands, just need to learn how to find that out :D

Comment: Try doing echo(exec('ls'));. If it returns a file listing, your host allows shell commands.

Comment: All i get is the string "sql" when run.

Comment: Have just realised that "sql" is the name of a folder on the host :) the file that is running the php exec function in in a folder called includes which is in a folder called admin and sql is also inside the admin folder like includes.